# Zend_Router route url to a specific module

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I'm using Zend, and here is my problem, i have two different urls that i really want to keep like they are.

i want url : "www.urlA.com" to be directed to application/moduleA/indexController/indexAction 
and "www.urlB.com" to application/index/index.

In other words, i want Zend_Router to make sure that when i type www.urlA.com/index/login i use the application/**moduleA**/ Index controller and loginAction().

I want to keep the classic Zend routing, just adding the fact that my module is already specified in the url.

I have the following code int the bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRouter()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
        'www.urlA.com',
        array(
            'module'=>'moduleA'
        )
    );
    $routeURI = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route();
    $router->addRoute('modulea', $route->chain($routeURI));
}
```

This way with the "urlA" i correctly go to moduleA/index/index but
"urlA/index/login" doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem once and I wrote this :

```
//ADMIN page
$admin = array('module' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index');
$hostRoute_admin = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('admin.mysite.com', $admin);

//special environement Website
$env = array('module' => 'env', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index');
$hostRoute_env = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('env.mysite.com', $env);

//Zend classic routing
$plainPathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':controller/:action/*',
        array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));

//add specific routing
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->addRoute('admin', $hostRoute_admin->chain($plainPathRoute));
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->addRoute('env', $hostRoute_env->chain($plainPathRoute));
```